# C# proper way to construct ISerializable interface?

Tags: c#, serialization, formatter

I recently made my own custom formatter, it takes a runtime object and writes down an object graph of it in a string format then takes that string and converts it back to a runtime object.
Example: `[CustomFormatter.Btype, CustomFormatter, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null==[a==5][b==0]]`

after messing around with primitive objects (`int`, `bool`, `float`...) I tried to serialize a `Bitmap` object into string using the `ISerializable` interface and it worked well but when I try to reconstruct the object back I'm getting an error `System.MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' not found.`

If bitmap doesn't have a constructor which takes SerializationInfo and StreamingContext as parameters how else can an object which inherits the `ISerializable` interface be constructed?

This part is is the main issue but I can include the whole code:

```
        private static object SeriObjConstructor(Type objType, ref string dataInfo, ref int location)
        {
            SerializationInfo info = new SerializationInfo(objType, new FormatterConverter());
            StreamingContext context = new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.All);
            location += serializerEntry.Length;
            while (!CheckHitOperator(dataInfo, serializerExit, ref location))
            {
                KeyValuePair<string, Type> serializedObj = GetSerialiedName(ref dataInfo, ref location); //<name, type>
                info.AddValue(serializedObj.Key, Construction(serializedObj.Value, ref dataInfo, ref location));
            }
            location += serializerExit.Length;
            location += endClass.Length;

            var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(objType, info, context); //THROWS AN ERROR
            return instance;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are forced to for legacy .NET Framework reasons, and you are taking over the role of the serializer engine: you can construct raw objects using `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject`. This API is explicitly intended for use with things like serialization, *but* should be treated as an advanced/exotic feature, and needs great care. Bad things can happen in some cases (fields not initialized, etc).

Quite honestly there is no correct way of working with the `ISerializable` interface in 2020 - that entire API is deprecated and obsolete, and isn't widely supported in .NET Core / .NET 5, and I would not recommend starting new work with it. More details about the problems/reasons are here: https://blog.marcgravell.com/2020/03/why-do-i-rag-on-binaryformatter.html, and many other, non-deprecated, serialization frameworks exist.

Comment: I've heard the BinaryFormatter isn't safe which is why I made my own formatter for education purposes and learn about security issues.
for basic objects I'm using `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject` but for other .Net objects like `Bitmap` such methods aren't effective.
I was wondering of there's a different way to initialize objects that inherit from `ISerializable`. if `BinaryFormatter` is able to serialize such complex objects I assume there's a special method to construct them, but I couldn't find one.
you know any open source formatters so I could learn how they dealt with it?

Comment: @Yoav usually a combination of checking for certain constructors (the ones that take certain types), parameterless, falling back to formatterservices - however, honestly IMO it is a mistake to serialize types like Bitmap (which are an implementation detail), rather than serializing the *data* (a blob, for example)